# Html tags not working in new Gmail app (version-7.5.7.156101332.release)

Tags: android

Just got a weird issue, same code was working fine with previous version but this recent gmail (version-7.5.7.156101332.release) update is not supporting Html tags.

Here is the code:

```
public static void sendMail(Activity activity){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/html");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , Html.fromHtml("<html><body><h1>Title</h1>body of email<br>New line</body></html>"));
        try {
            activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How does the email show up?

Comment: normal text, just <br> tag works

Comment: Have you tried adding also the `html` and `body` tags?

Comment: @nonzaprej yes, still does not work